# Reproduzir música no meu aplicativo Android

Tags: android, lista

Estou querendo fazer uma lista com nomes de músicas , e quando clicar em cima de algum item da lista reproduzir a música. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Estava procurando em sites por aí e achei isso:

```
public void playAudio(View view){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.musica1);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    });
    mp.start();
}
```

Funcionou para reproduzir a música quando clica no botão.

Usei este R.raw.musica1 , este musica1 e o nome da minha música, tem como eu colocar ele em uma string ou direto em uma lista?

Comment: Basta criar uma `Activity` com os nomes das músicas e então chamar a API de reprodução do Android quando uma delas for "clickada". Brincadeiras a parte, o que você tentou?

Comment: To querendo uma luz , porque nunca fiz nada com musica em android

Comment: Como aparentemente você não tem nada feito, procure separar suas dúvidas. Acredito que primeiro você vá precisar de obter a lista das músicas para colocar em um `ListView`. Mas de onde vem as músicas? Da biblioteca do *Android*? Do próprio aplicativo? Da "nuvem"? Depois disse você passa para o segundo desafio que é reproduzir esta música. Enfim, é melhor segmentar sua dúvida para ficar mais fácil, do jeito que está é amplo demais.

Comment: ata. o complicado para mim e fazer a reprodução da musica, pensei em colocar ela no aplicativo mesmo em uma pasta no res. colocar na lista depois vou ver como vou fazer vou ter que definir nomes para as musicas